# Some questions about the mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I am a beginner that study the mixed effect model recently,

I feel very confused about mixed effect model,

so I list two common question for this topic,

if I had a model contain the fixed effect and random effects,

1. What is the population mean in mixed effect model?
2. How do I consider the effect over time in mixed effect model?

Hope someone can give direction for me, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you make your problem more specific? Provide an example of dataset + model? As for your second question, there are many ways of taking time into account in a mixed-effect model, but that depends a lot on what "time" is, i.e. it can be comparing scores at two specific time points, or comparing finely the evolution of a variable during time.